# Make the message multiline in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a page that allows users to send messages. But users only can send the one-line messages. I want users to enable send multiline messages by clicking shift+enter. How can I do this? The current react code is:

```
<div className="p-3 chat-input-section">
                              <Row>
                                <Col>
                                  <div className="position-relative">
                                    <input
                                      type="text"
                                      value={curMessage}
                                      onChange={e => {
                                        setcurMessage(e.target.value)
                                        setDisable(true)
                                      }}
                                      onKeyDown={e => {
                                        if (e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey) {
                                          e.preventDefault() // Prevents the default behavior of Enter key (form submission)
                                          sendMessage()
                                        }
                                      }}
                                      className="form-control chat-input"
                                      placeholder="Enter Message..."
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                </Col>
                                <Col className="col-auto">
                                  <Button
                                    type="button"
                                    color="primary"
                                    disabled={!isdisable}
                                    onClick={() => sendMessage()}
                                    className="btn btn-primary btn-rounded chat-send w-md"
                                  >
                                    <span className="d-none d-sm-inline-block me-2">
                                      Send
                                    </span>{" "}
                                    <i className="mdi mdi-send" />
                                  </Button>
                                </Col>
                              </Row>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To enable users to send multiline messages by pressing Shift+Enter, you can modify your code to use a textarea element instead of an input element. Here's an example of how you can do this in React:*

```
   <div className="p-3 chat-input-section">
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <div className="position-relative">
            <textarea
              type="text"
              value={curMessage}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setcurMessage(e.target.value);
                setDisable(true);
              }}
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                if (e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey) {
                  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default behavior of Enter key (form submission)
                  sendMessage();
                }
              }}
              className="form-control chat-input"
              placeholder="Enter Message..."
            />
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col className="col-auto">
          <Button
            type="button"
            color="primary"
            disabled={!isdisable}
            onClick={() => sendMessage()}
            className="btn btn-primary btn-rounded chat-send w-md"
          >
            <span className="d-none d-sm-inline-block me-2">Send</span>{" "}
            <i className="mdi mdi-send" />
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
```

Comment: Indeed, the multiline feature is operational. It appends '\n' to the message for each new line. However, upon displaying the sent messages, they appear concatenated into a single line. I am employing a <p> component to render the message. Could this behavior be related to its implementation?

Comment: @MuhammedDidin, Yes, the behavior you're experiencing is likely related to how the messages are rendered using the <p> component. By default, the <p> element collapses whitespace, including newline characters (\n), which causes the messages to appear as a single line.

To render the messages with preserved line breaks, you can use the CSS white-space: pre-line; property on the <p> element or its parent container. This property instructs the browser to preserve newline characters and display the text with line breaks.
Like provide style to your div- style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}